# Json Parsing for bounced emails in python in AWS SES

Tags: python, json, parsing, amazon-sns

I am trying to write a lambda function for AWS SNS to catch the bounced emails. I could successfully catch the details for notification type "Delivery" but not for type "bounce". Some syntax issue in python, I dont know python but no other option in SES. My code is below.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

message = event.get("Records")[0].get("Sns").get("Message")
parsed_message = json.loads(message)
status = parsed_message.get("notificationType")
event_date = parsed_message.get("mail").get("timestamp")
recipients = []

if (status == "Bounce"):
    for r in parsed_message.get("bounce").get("bouncedRecipients"):
        parsed_r = json.loads(r)
        recipients.append(parsed_r[0].get("emailAddress"))
elif (status == "Complaint"):
    for r in parsed_message.get("complaint").get("complainedRecipients"):
        recipients.append(r)
elif (status == "Delivery"):
    for r in parsed_message.get("delivery").get("recipients"):
        recipients.append(r)

conn = make_conn()
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("insert into email_event (email_status, event_date, email_address, event_json) values (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (status, event_date, ";".join(recipients), json.dumps(event)))
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Json for parsed_message is below

```
 {
   "notificationType": "Bounce",
   "bounce": {
      "bounceType": "Permanent",
      "bounceSubType": "Suppressed",
      "bouncedRecipients": [
         {
            "emailAddress": "email@email.com",
            "action": "failed",
            "status": "5.1.1",
            "diagnosticCode": "Amazon SES has suppressed sending to this address because it has a recent history of bouncing as an invalid address. "
         }
      ],

   },
```

I am getting the error like this 
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict': TypeError

I tried like below

```
for r in parsed_message.get("bounce").get("bouncedRecipients")[0].get("emailAddress")
recipients.append(r)
```

but this get saved in the DB as e;m;a;i;l;@;e;m;a;i;l;.;c;o;m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"bouncedRecipients" points to a list of dicts, one for each bounced recipient.

To iterate over that list, and then get the email address should look like:

```
for r in parsed_message.get("bounce").get("bouncedRecipients"):
    recipients.append(r.get("emailAddress"))
```

Or, less like Java and more like Python:

```
for r in parsed_message["bounce"]["bouncedRecipients"]:
    recipients.append(r["emailAddress"])
```

Which can also be written as a list comprehension as:

```
recipients = [r["emailAddress"] for r in parsed_message["bounce"]["bouncedRecipients"]]
```